# Check if all required are empty or filled in a form created with Orbeon Forms

Tags: forms, xpath, orbeon, required

I would to test if all required inputs in my form are empty or not, knowing that I have more than 20 required inputs.

**EDIT:**
I tried with this formulas xpath (if($fr-mode='validate') then 'the form was complete' else 'the form was incomplete' in the calculated value of the field.but didn't work after submiting the form and retyping all required fields

Comment: Is this for a form you created in Form Builder, or are you writing XForms "by hand"? And what action would you like to take if you find that not all the required fields have a value? Also, is it any different if a field has a value, but the value isn't value?

Comment: Yes i write xforms in Form Builder,I want when one of required fields is empty  a string field will be activated

Comment: OK. When a required field is left empty and the user tabs out, a message will be shown below the field. Are you saying that you'd like to have a custom message? If so, you can change the message in Control Settings, in the Validations and Alerts tab. Would that work for you, or are you looking for something different?

Comment: no for something different like when i submit the form an input field was filled with this message "the form was incompleted"

Comment: Lebki, so the user clicks on "Submit", and if everything is valid, then the form is submitted, otherwise the value of an input field field is set to "the form was incomplete", and users stay on the form. Is that what you are saying? -Alex

Comment: yes Alex, i tried with this formulas xpath (if($fr-mode='validate') then 'the form was complete' else 'the form was incomplete' in the calculated value of the field.but didn't work  after submiting the form and retyping all required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input')

var isAnyFilled = false;

for (var i = 0; i<elements.lenght; i++) {
    if (elements[i].value) {
        isAnyFilled = true;
        break;
     }
}

console.log(isAnyFilled);
```